# Using C# Attributes to take inputs to make a UI agnostic system

Tags: c#, attributes, plugins

```
public class MyPlugin : IPluginSystem
{
    [ExternalInput]
    public String myExternalProperty { get; set; }

    public bool execute()
    {
         if (myExternalProperty.Equals("My setter is called from elsewhere"))
             return true;
         return false;
    }
}
```

Is this possible? How would I achieve this? Would I need to specify typeof(X) also there in the attribute?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I would really encourage you to consider going in another direction. I've seen more than a few developers go down this road and it never ends well - either abandoned; or an unmaintainable, convoluted monstrosity forced into production.

Comment: I'm trying to create a build/configuration system. And In fact I am using MEF.

Comment: So it's mostly like a Workflow:

(1) install x
(2) Run Y (depends on X)
(3) Do Z (requires input from user, for example, a String input).

So I don't want my user to interact directly with the plugin, but my main app builds a UI for them, based on these things.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) (Managed Extensibility Framework) if you haven't.  From the look of what you want to do, it's a perfect match.

Comment: Well, I am using MEF! MEF allows me to specify imports and exports, it doesn't let me propogate inputs to my parts, which can be made at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'd just need something to bind those to a UI - I'll take an easy way out and assume a form with a single textbox. Depending on your requirements, a PropertyInfo grid or something may be more appropriate.

Something like:

```
class PluginUIBuilder {
    public void Fill(IPluginSystem p) {
       var t = ((object)p).GetType();
       foreach (var pi in t.GetProperties()) {
          if (pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExternalInput), true).Length > 0) {
             string value = Prompt(pi.Name);
             pi.SetValue(p, value, null);
          }
       }
    }

    string Prompt(string name) {
       using (var f = new InputForm()) {
          f.Prompt = "Enter a value for " + name;
          if (f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) {
             return f.Value;
          }
          return null;
       }
    }
}

// client code
var p = new MyPlugin();

var ui = new PluginUIBuilder();
ui.Fill(p);

p.Execute();
```

You'll probably want to add properties to your attribute for things like descriptions, a convert function or class (may want to leverage the builtin [type converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx)), validation, etc.

At the end of the day, if you take this too far - you've just built the WinForm design surface. But, I've used Property Info grids for prompts for otherwise command line apps to decent success with very little code.

Comment: how would I do this, for things in other assemblies?

Comment: Basically, you just need the System.Type - so if you're dynamically loading the Assembly, then you can use Assembly.GetTypes(). If you're loading from a config file or something, then you can use Type.GetType(string). Etc, etc.